# Exact search in Windows 10 for term with parentheses

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, file-search

I wish to remove specific duplicate files that for some reason appeared on my system.
I know I might be able to do that with shell, but I'm not familiar with it and don't have much need for it other than in this specific occasion.

What I want to do is search for all filenames that end with "(1)", for example:

> filename (1).jpg

I tried searching for (1) with or without quotes, but for some reason it treats the parentheses as junk and gives me everything in that folder with a "1" inside. I also added a space, i.e. " (1)", but same results again.

Any trick up anyone's sleave?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the program "Everything"
[(website)](https://www.voidtools.com/). It allows you to seach for parentheses. Searching for "(1)." will work fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for "filename (1).jpg" this will return files that contain *filename (1)*, parenthesis included.

The reason The parenthesis were ignored in the first place is that parentheses e.g. (social security) [finds items that contain social and security in any order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference). You can Find uses for other special characters [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax).

Behind the scenes, Windows file explorer search interprets your search using Advanced Query Syntax.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).